# react widgets combobox open while clicking input

Tags: reactjs

http://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/api/Combobox/
The example in the docs link above shows two styles ComboBoxes. One on the left which is

```
Individual component
import Combobox from 'react-widgets/lib/Combobox'
```

Then on the right labeled filter has

```
 Main export
import { Combobox } from 'react-widgets'
```

I'm trying to get the one on the right to render but it keeps rendering it looking like the react-widgets/lib/Combobox.

Here is my code below. Th issue is I want to be able to select anywhere on the combobox to trigger the dropdown. The one on the right does that while the one on the left you have to click the arrow icon in order to get it to open.
Is there a prop to set this or what am I missing ?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Combobox } from 'react-widgets';

export default field => (
  <div>
    <Combobox
      defaultValue={field.data[0]}
      data={field.data}
    />
  </div>
);
```

The combobox on the right which I have outlined in red on the image below is the one I'm trying to get working. But my above code keeps rendering the one on the left.

[image]

**UPDATE:** for anyone having this same issue. The reason they look styled differently is because on the right side they are not using a combobox but instead they are using a dropdownlist widget.

Comment: Can you make a CodeSandbox?

Comment: Thats why I added the link so you could see both Comboboxes at the top of the links page

Comment: Well, I wanted to run your code.

Comment: I tried to add it to a fiddle but it wont run at all.

Comment: Did you add it to [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)?

Comment: No I had to use dropdowList instead of combobox that's why the styling was different. But thanks for checking back